# Javascript: change image and text during mouseover/mouseout on link

Tags: javascript

In my javascript Program I have created a page to display an image and description at the same time when the user moves the mouseOver a link, and display a different image with no description when user moves the mouseOut of link. but I am not getting output on mouseOver/mouseOut as per expectation. Can anyone help ? I did the following:

(i) When the mouse moves over a link, I am calling the function by passing the text and image.

(ii) When the mouse moves out,I am calling the function by passing a blank text and a different image. This image is the same when the mouse is out from all the links.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>

    div a{

        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: yellow;
    }

    .container {
        width: 1002px;
        margin-top: 50px;
        margin-left: 130px;

    }
    #first {
        width: 400px;
        float: left;
        height: 350px;
        background-color:#f4b2ef;
        border:inset;
    }
    #second {
        width: 590px;
        float: right;
        height: 350px;
        color: white;
        border:inset;   
    }

</style>
<title>mouseover/out</title>
</head>
<body background="images/back.jpg">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: monospace; color: white; font-size: 35px">PHOTO  CONTEST </h1>
    <div class='container'>
        <div id="first">
            <a href="#" onMouseOver="replaceImg(this)" onMouseOut="defaultImg(this)"><p style="text-align:center">First Place Winner</p></a> 
            <a href="#" onMouseOver="replaceImg2(this)" onMouseOut="defaultImg2(this)"><p style="text-align:center">Third Place Winner</p></a> 
            <a href="#" onMouseOver="replaceImg3(this)" onMouseOut="defaultImg3(this)"><p style="text-align:center">Merit Prize Winner</p></a> 

            <p id="para">  </p>
        </div>

        <div id="second">
            <img id="default" src="images/default.jpeg" alt=""
            width="590" height="350"/>

        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var blank = "";
        var txt = "Beautiful fall";
        var txt2 = "Natural pictures are beautiful";
        var txt3 = "Beautiful Rose garden"

        var w1 = new Image(590, 350);
        var w2 = new Image(590, 350);
        var w3 = new Image(590, 350);

        var def = new Image(590, 350);

        w1.src = "images/w1.jpeg";
        w2.src = "images/w2.jpg";
        w3.src = "images/w3.jpg";

        def.src = "images/default.jpeg";

        function replaceImg(txt, w1) {
            w1.src;
            var para = document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = txt;

        }

        function defaultImg(blank, def) {
            def.src;    
            var para = document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = blank;
        }




    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code has several issues. Only one parameter is passed to the function

Comment: `w1.src s2.src def.src` doesn't do what you might think could be doing, you're just accessing that variable but doing nothing with it

Comment: How should I make it correct ?

Comment: Can anyone help ?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/J9gRxuSWlV5lH5gOYm9n?p=preview

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for your response but it's still it's not working as per expectation. There should be only three images and text should also change when user mouseOver link.

Comment: That is a start.

Comment: ok sure.........

Answer (score 1):

I amputate your code just to demonstrate that you can make it work by using js function `addEventListener("moustover",callback)` to do the work. I have never wrote code in your way so I don't know how to improve upon yours. You should always seperate your html css and js codes.

```js
var firstTarget = document.querySelector("#first");
firstTarget.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
  document.querySelector("#target-image").setAttribute("src",'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150)');
})
firstTarget.addEventListener("mouseout",function(){
  document.querySelector("#target-image").setAttribute("src",'#');
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>mouseover/out</title>
</head>
<body background="images/back.jpg">
    <h1 style="text-align: center; font-family: monospace; color: white; font-size: 35px">PHOTO  CONTEST </h1>
    <div class='container'>
        <div id="first">
            <a href="#" ><p style="text-align:center">First Place Winner</p></a> 
        </div> 
        <div>
          <img id="target-image" src="#" alt="">
          </div>
    </div>
```